# Restrict Users from adding to groups manually in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I need to restrict the users from adding to the groups manually in Azure, any help on this issue?

Comment: Give users to the reader permission or give contributor where he can't assign the permission at subscription

Comment: thanks rahul...... How about the user is an admin and we need to restrict him from adding users??

Comment: Add review process in places where if any user gets added in the group you will get notification for the same and based on your approval only it will gets added

Comment: review in the terms pls???

Comment: Follow this article for the step by step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-create-azure-ad-roles-and-resource-roles-review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  @Rahul Shukla for your suggestion .

> 1. Restrict Users from adding to groups

Give the user with **reader** or **contributor** permission  to the user .
if you add that user the reader permission they will then be able to read any resource in the subscription, but not modify anything.

For more details refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current

> 2)Prevent admin to add the users to group

Create  review process in places where if any user gets added in the group admin  will get notification for the same and based on admin approval only it will gets added.

Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) access reviews enable organizations to efficiently manage group memberships, access to enterprise applications, and role assignments. User's access can be reviewed on a regular basis to make sure only the right people have continued access

For more details refer this document:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/access-reviews-overview

Comment: Thanks very much shruthi  thats a brief description. thanks for spending some time on this  :)

Comment: if we created a flow for a user when response is submitted should be added to that group with approval and what if the adder user is by default an admin and he should be restricted from adding other members